# ActionBarSherlock Switch Toggle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to put a master switch toggle on the action bar and I'm 
having zero luck.. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank 
you.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_action_provider_action_bar"> 
<Switch android:id="@+id/monitored_switch" 
            android:text="Monitored switch" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:showAsAction = "always" /> 
</item> 
</menu>
```

and

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); 
    return true; 
}
```

I'm positive that the menu is being created and displayed because if I 
add other items they show. Just not the toggle.. And I'm testing on an 
AVD running 4.0.3 and my phone running 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom view to the action bar's menu using an [`action view`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); 
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)); 
}
```

I don't know if this will change anything for you but it's worth a try :)

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I actually figured out what I was looking for. It ended up being you can't add switches into the menu. So I added the switch into a relativelayout .xml and added it to the actionbar by: 

`View toggle = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.locate_toggle, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(toggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, why using ActionBar Sherlock if you use a switch? switch appeared with API 14, which doesn't need a compatibility framework :) (I'm just curious)

Comment: Probably not this guy's reason, but one might want to show an on/off switch in API 14+, and on lower APIs throw a checkbox in there instead (by checking the build at run time).

Comment: Yep, I can understand that, I faced the problem some weeks ago :)

Comment: @Josh Why use a checkbox? The Switch widget has been back-ported to API 7. I might encourage swapping the native for non-native implementation but otherwise it works flawlessly. https://github.com/Tombarr/android-switch-backport

Comment: Thanks for the link Tom, nice port.  Users on lower APIs won't be expecting switches in their apps, that's all.  Some devs would prefer their apps to look the same across all platforms, while some prefer their apps to look like the other apps on the user's phone (which would likely have checkboxes).